# Problem parsing Django radio button when trying to set checked attribute

Tags: django, if-statement, radio-button

I need to build a set of radio buttons using Django.  I've taken the approach of doing this in a template rather than a Django Form class as I was hoping it would give me more flexibility.

I'm running into a problem when trying to conditionally add a checked attribut to preselect which radio is selected when the form loads.

The code below works.  It renders the 4 radio buttons and selects the last one.  This is just a test obviously as this would always leave the last button selected.  But it proves my model, view and template all work.

```
        {% for choice in thisSQwithQ.qid.GetChoices %}
        <input type="radio"  name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.choiceid }}" checked="checked" >

        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
        {% endfor %}
```

But, when I add the Django code to conditionally set checked="checked" for each radio, I'm getting a really odd syntax error.

The following code gives me an error "Could not parse the remainder: '==' from 'selected_value=='"

```
        {% for choice in thisSQwithQ.qid.GetChoices %}
        <input type="radio"  name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.choiceid }}" {% if selected_value== choice.choiceid %} checked="checked" {% endif %} >

        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
        {% endfor %}
```

I've had a good grapple with this for a day now ;-)

Could anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need to add a whitespace in your condition.

```
{% if selected_value== choice.choiceid %}
```

will becomes :

```
{% if selected_value == choice.choiceid %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bit more complex than that.  Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: You still have same error after adding the whitespace?

Comment: Yes.  I've tried all sorts of things like that.

I think my syntax is correct so I'm not sure why it's kicking up that error.